# KNN model (using PCA) outputs same accuracy over each iteration of k

Tags: python, pca, knn

I am fairly new to machine learning techniques and I'm trying to wrap my head around the implementation of PCA and KNN to classify different outputs.

I am using a dataset of handwritten numbers from 0 to 9. The training set has shape of (60000,784) and the testing set has shape of (10000,784). I use PCA to reduce the dimensionality to the first 6 principal components, so now my training set has shape of (60000,6) and testing set has (10000,6). I attempt to perform an iteration over different k values, ranging from 1 to 17, to extract the best possible k value for my application. However, when I do this I keep getting 0.2023 for my accuracy. I feel this is incorrect and was wondering what I could possibly be doing wrong.

Here is my code, where I perform the PCA and my attempt at extracting the optimal K value:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=6)
train_projected = pca.fit_transform(X_train_norm)
test_projected = pca.fit_transform(X_test_norm)
```

For my normalized arrays, I just divided them by 255 as that is the max possible value.

```
k_range = range(1,17)
scores = {};
scores_list = [];
for i in k_range:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    knn.fit(train_projected,y_train)
    pred = knn.predict(test_projected)
    scores[i] = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,pred)
    scores_list.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,pred))

print('Scores ', scores,'\n')
print('Scores List ',scores_list,'\n')

Scores  {1: 0.2023, 2: 0.2023, 3: 0.2023, 4: 0.2023, 5: 0.2023, 6: 0.2023, 7: 0.2023, 8: 0.2023, 9: 0.2023, 10: 0.2023, 11: 0.2023, 12: 0.2023, 13: 0.2023, 14: 0.2023, 15: 0.2023, 16: 0.2023, 17: 0.2023, 18: 0.2023, 19: 0.2023, 20: 0.2023, 21: 0.2023, 22: 0.2023, 23: 0.2023, 24: 0.2023, 25: 0.2023, 26: 0.2023}

Scores List  [0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023, 0.2023]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake!

In this code:

```
for i in k_range:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
```

You are setting `n_neighbors=k` for each iteration. It should be `n_neighbors=i`